# Web2py Deployment issue: can't make server live

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to implement web2py in EC2. I followed simple official guide but its not working for me. [**These**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-web2py-python-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) are the steps I've followed just now and I can't open it in my local browser. Objective here is to access site from EC2 deployment to server locally on my home computer. Can someone please point me to right direction? Thanks

Comment: You have not posted any code that you are trying? No other details. How can one help you?

Comment: Its a simple web2py instance and all the web2py files are same. By default it has option to be implemented with different socket laters like with HTTPD or uWsgi or Gunicorn. All I am looking for which is the best approach to get it live. Because I tried few and I guess I am missing out something. I simply did what is mentioned in link in above question. Here is the documentation http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Web2Py folder there is '/scripts' and it helps you to deploy web2py from scratch automatically. You don't need to do any research, just run one of the script according to the type of your machine you are using on EC2. Coz there are different scripts as per OS. Run the shell script with root and that's it. You can access your site at ip:8000 by default. You can change the .sh or script file if you need to use some other port for deployment in test phase. @Tarun it doesn't hurt to click on a link and I am doing this all the time when coders paste gist around.

Comment: I found scripts and it has even ssl creation automated in it. Let me try and I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: @Alikhan follow the official repo. https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/master/scripts